# Would a single collision of human vocal folds cause an audible sound?

Tags: physiology

If it were possible to only exhale enough air to cause a single collision, would that be audible?

Comment: why should inceased exhaling air generate collision (collapsing) vocal folds?  Or is it the question if human vocal folds can generate pulses similar to phonic lips on toothed whales?

Comment: I suppose I am misunderstanding what is happening. I thought that when we speak we make the noise by using air to collide our vocal folds. The noise of our voice is made by colliding our vocal folds, right? If they were to collide(however they collide) just once then would the noise of that be audible?